# Cinnamon: How to get path in text on GUI window, and how to open terminal at current GUI-window location?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nautilus

I want to know how to set it so that I see the graphical directory path in text instead of buttons in Cinnamon.

I also want to know a way to open a terminal at the GUI-window's current path. Like right-click/open terminal at current location.

I think I used to have those options, but somehow they disappeared. I don't know why. Maybe something got updated or something.

I seem to have Nautilus 3.10.1

Comment: In Cinnamon using what program? You mean in the default file manager, `caja`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to `caja`, the default file manager on Cinnamon, you can get the path by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and you can open a terminal by right clicking and selecting the relevant option:

[image]

The screenshot above was taken on Cinnamon 2.2.16 and caja caja 1.8.2.

Comment: Ctrl-L works, however right-click doesn't show that option. Also how to permanently set the text path?

Comment: @JohnyTex what version are you running and are you sure it's `caja` and not another file manager? Check Help->About.

Comment: I believe I have Nautilus. What does it mean? Should I change?

Comment: @JohnyTex no, not at all. First, are you _sure_ it's nautilus? It is actually probably `nemo`. Either way, please [edit] your question and include the specific name and version. You should be able to find them in Help -> About. I have the "open in terminal" option on nautilus, caja and nemo.

Comment: If I choose Help about I cant find it. I go to menu applications, help, and then there is a small text saying about, but it doesnt tell u anything but the license

Comment: @JohnyTex there should be a Help menu in the file manager itself. Next to File, Edit, View etc.

Comment: It says. About Files. Files 3.10.1. It talks about GNU and Nautilus, so I suppose it is Nautilus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18994/discussion-between-terdon-and-johnytex).